# UIView and TableView resizable

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, tableview

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIBlY.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4AZB.png)

As you see, i have storyboard like in pic 1, but in simulator it looks like in pic 2.
How can i make it, thats this tableView inside View will be fullsized if contains some data. If not - it will be hidden.

At this moment, if its contains some data, UIview doesnt change the height and uitableview is almost not visible.

This lines didnt help:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

------------------part 2--------here is code of viewController---------

```
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var details: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonAdd: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var variation: AutoSizingTableView!
    
    
    var selectedImage: UIImage?
    var selectedName: String?
    var selectedPrice: String?
    var selectedDetails: String?
    var selectedVariation: NSDictionary?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        variation.delegate = self
        variation.dataSource = self
        variation.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        view.frame.size = variation.intrinsicContentSize
//        view.frame.size = variation.intrinsicContentSize
        variation.reloadData()
//        variation.layoutIfNeeded()
//        variation.frame.size = variation.intrinsicContentSize
//        variation.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        variation.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        variation.isScrollEnabled = false
        variation.isHidden = false
        buttonAdd.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        image.image = selectedImage
        name.text = selectedName
        price.text = selectedPrice
        details.text = selectedDetails
        
        

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        print(selectedVariation?.allKeys.count)
    
    }
    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

extension DetailsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return selectedVariation?.allKeys.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Variation", for: indexPath)
//        if selectedVariation != nil {
//            for i in selectedVariation {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "test test"
        return cell
        }
  
    
}
class AutoSizingTableView: UITableView {
    
      override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
          self.layoutIfNeeded()
          return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
      }
      
      override var contentSize: CGSize {
          didSet{
              self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
          }
      }
      
      override func reloadData() {
          super.reloadData()
          self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
      }
    
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function of `estimatedRowHeight` and setting a `rowHeight` for a tableView is to set the height for the tableView cells and **not the height of the tableView itself**.

As you insert or delete cells into your tableView, `contentSize` of the tableView changes.

**Solution 1**:
You could use the below subclass of UITableView which automatically changes it's `intrinsicContentSize` as it's `contentSize` changes so AutoLayout can take care of the rest. Use this subclass instead of *UITableView* in your view controller.
If your tableView has no cells, the `intrinsicContentSize` height could be set to 0.

I'd recommend you to read more about a view's intrinsic content size [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize).

```
class AutoSizingTableView: UITableView{
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
    
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet{
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    
    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**:
You could manually add a **height constraint** to your tableView and change it's constant as required based on the contentSize or if you have additional requirements as per your design specifications.

Comment: i think you gave right suggestion, but im learning swift just a couple months, not exactly sure how to use it right. at first i wrote this line of code. Changed in storyboard a class of tableview to class AutoSizingTableView. Made an @IBOutlet weak var tableview: AutoSizingTableView! in my viewController. And how exactly i can call autoresizing methods?

Comment: need your help) im stuck there, but should move

Comment: Just making your tableView as an instance of AutoSizingTableView should be enough provided there are no other constraints limiting/modifying its height. What is the result you get after changing the class?

Comment: i have just one height constraints to my imageview. Otherwise its all images have different sizes. Without height contsraint of image, i can see all data just because its make photo smaller, but the size of View is the same

Comment: If you could share a sample project so I can check the constraints that would be great. I'm unable to debug this without looking at the constraints you have in place for your views. Also, the `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` method on the tableView need not be called in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Is the `variation` tableView added as a subView of `view` in your view controller? In that case, users would not be able to scroll down to view the contents of the `variation` table view that you have. Make sure you have embedded all your views in a parent scroll view or have separate cells for each section in UI within a new parent tableview.

Comment: i've added extra picture of view controller. if it will help u to understand what is wrong.i havent scroll view at all. whats the best way to share a project? Github?

Comment: Add a `UIScrollView` to the view and set it to the full size of the controller, make your main stackview a subview of the scroll view you have added. Add a width constraint so that with of the stack view equals the width of the scroll view along with leading trailing top and bottom constraints. Doing this should solve it. The layout you have now isn't scrollable by the user. And sure if you are unable to do the above, you can upload a sample project to Github and I'll have a look :)

Comment: I've tried a fix for you on Github and it works. The issue you had was due to constraints not being set. Please check out the changes made. If you could mark the answer as accepted that would be great.
We went on quite a tangent solving other issues as well :)

Comment: are u alive? I think i need your help with a similar problem )  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537311/swift-collectionview-and-tableview-in-scrollview