# Swift CollectionView and TableView in ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

So, how you can see in pic below, i have collectionView and TableView in ScrollView. And it works not how i expected. You can see the problem in gif picture. The CollectionView has static height = 100 and tableview has selfsizeble height.StackView's height and width are equal to height and width of ScrollView. It looks like there is somewhere a tiny mistake, but i cant find it out.

here AutoSizeClass for TableView:

```
class AutoSizingTableView: UITableView {
    
      override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
          self.layoutIfNeeded()
          return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
      }
      
      override var contentSize: CGSize {
          didSet{
              self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
          }
      }
      
      override func reloadData() {
          super.reloadData()
          self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
      }
    
  }
```

The problem is that View with Collection View staying in the same place and doesnt scroll up.

[image] [image: How it works]

Comment: You need to show your constraints, and the code you're using for *"tableview has selfsizeble height"* to get any help with this.

Comment: i edeted the question.All consraints in pic, except ScrollView. Scrollview has 0 top, bottom, Leading and Trailing

Comment: Do you want your horizontal scrolling collection view to remain visible? Or is it supposed to scroll up off the screen when you scroll the table view up?

Comment: it supposed to scroll up and should be invisible. but instead it staying in the same place behind the tableview

Comment: I would ***strongly*** recommend that you use a standard `UITableViewController` and put your collection view in the first cell.

Comment: If you, for some reason, want to keep your current layout - stack view with view holding collection view and table view inside a scroll view... did you disable scrolling on your table view?

Comment: i tried, but with disabled scrolling in tableview it non scrollable at all.

Comment: Then you’re doing something else wrong. Is there a reason you don’t want to use a standard table view with your collection view in the first cell / row?

Comment: There is actually no reason, but it should work this way too. But how i think , there are some mistakes with constraints.  Will try to find the problem.If i will not find then will put collectionview in first cell.

Comment: I just posted an answer with a complete example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment *"with disabled scrolling in tableview it non scrollable at all"* ... you've done something wrong with your setup.

Here is how it needs to be laid-out in Storyboard to get it to work. Note that the table view ***must*** have scrolling **disabled**:

[image]

Here is the source to that Storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="for-Xa-JUC">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="collection view cell content view" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Azdaev View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="UV2-bp-BSw">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="for-Xa-JUC" customClass="AzdaevViewController" customModule="TableAdd" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Aiw-Z0-OHR">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NiW-5R-cfc">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Iqj-ag-gPR">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="348"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Ewg-bZ-eyT">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="100"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <collectionView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" dataMode="prototypes" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PVP-gp-7EW">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="100"/>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                                                        <constraints>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="100" id="4ie-da-XpJ"/>
                                                        </constraints>
                                                        <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" scrollDirection="horizontal" automaticEstimatedItemSize="YES" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" id="JhR-eW-5b9">
                                                            <size key="itemSize" width="80" height="80"/>
                                                            <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                                            <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                                            <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
                                                        </collectionViewFlowLayout>
                                                        <cells>
                                                            <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="SimpleCollCell" id="znX-Ra-Axt" customClass="SimpleCollCell" customModule="TableAdd" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="10" width="80" height="80"/>
                                                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                                <collectionViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="GWE-KA-31W">
                                                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="80" height="80"/>
                                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                                    <subviews>
                                                                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7U6-uF-qZB">
                                                                            <rect key="frame" x="19" y="30" width="42" height="20.5"/>
                                                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                                        </label>
                                                                    </subviews>
                                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                                    <constraints>
                                                                        <constraint firstItem="7U6-uF-qZB" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="GWE-KA-31W" secondAttribute="centerY" id="8E5-5k-QqV"/>
                                                                        <constraint firstItem="7U6-uF-qZB" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="GWE-KA-31W" secondAttribute="centerX" id="FTH-Df-wyE"/>
                                                                    </constraints>
                                                                </collectionViewCellContentView>
                                                                <connections>
                                                                    <outlet property="theLabel" destination="7U6-uF-qZB" id="kcQ-Wy-2wY"/>
                                                                </connections>
                                                            </collectionViewCell>
                                                        </cells>
                                                    </collectionView>
                                                </subviews>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="PVP-gp-7EW" secondAttribute="trailing" id="941-fg-5DC"/>
                                                    <constraint firstItem="PVP-gp-7EW" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Ewg-bZ-eyT" secondAttribute="top" id="9kx-ps-iUv"/>
                                                    <constraint firstItem="PVP-gp-7EW" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Ewg-bZ-eyT" secondAttribute="leading" id="OYx-qn-7cl"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="PVP-gp-7EW" secondAttribute="bottom" id="OgJ-Yv-Jal"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </view>
                                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" placeholderIntrinsicWidth="infinite" placeholderIntrinsicHeight="240" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" scrollEnabled="NO" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="XGR-gS-YDa" customClass="ContentSizedTableView" customModule="TableAdd" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="108" width="375" height="240"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                                                <prototypes>
                                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="SimpleTableCell" id="LTQ-ke-1N0" customClass="SimpleTableCell" customModule="TableAdd" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="43"/>
                                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="LTQ-ke-1N0" id="ILn-2o-e6E">
                                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="43"/>
                                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                            <subviews>
                                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="QxE-9g-2Hm">
                                                                    <rect key="frame" x="15" y="11" width="345" height="21"/>
                                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </subviews>
                                                            <constraints>
                                                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="QxE-9g-2Hm" secondAttribute="bottom" id="2kY-7j-i6k"/>
                                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="QxE-9g-2Hm" secondAttribute="trailing" id="8Rb-MN-fCq"/>
                                                                <constraint firstItem="QxE-9g-2Hm" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ILn-2o-e6E" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="IFx-mV-xVp"/>
                                                                <constraint firstItem="QxE-9g-2Hm" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ILn-2o-e6E" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="SkZ-FP-3Xk"/>
                                                            </constraints>
                                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                                        <connections>
                                                            <outlet property="theLabel" destination="QxE-9g-2Hm" id="tCs-qB-RnZ"/>
                                                        </connections>
                                                    </tableViewCell>
                                                </prototypes>
                                            </tableView>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Iqj-ag-gPR" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="cNU-lA-jis" secondAttribute="width" id="YWn-il-cIA"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Iqj-ag-gPR" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="78Z-qi-tb8" secondAttribute="bottom" id="dWW-mF-X02"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Iqj-ag-gPR" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="78Z-qi-tb8" secondAttribute="leading" id="jlB-bm-lOp"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Iqj-ag-gPR" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="78Z-qi-tb8" secondAttribute="top" id="oPw-KA-7Eb"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Iqj-ag-gPR" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="78Z-qi-tb8" secondAttribute="trailing" id="t90-TH-ogv"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="78Z-qi-tb8"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="cNU-lA-jis"/>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="NiW-5R-cfc" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="kCj-qX-p52" secondAttribute="top" id="18n-ZT-7rU"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NiW-5R-cfc" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="kCj-qX-p52" secondAttribute="leading" id="1BY-QR-X5K"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NiW-5R-cfc" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="kCj-qX-p52" secondAttribute="trailing" id="YHh-qb-ygU"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NiW-5R-cfc" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="kCj-qX-p52" secondAttribute="bottom" id="tzd-Zo-fNv"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="kCj-qX-p52"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="theCollectionView" destination="PVP-gp-7EW" id="MxW-WG-GPj"/>
                        <outlet property="theTableView" destination="XGR-gS-YDa" id="NhY-EO-L3y"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="nbL-KS-cva" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="447.82608695652175" y="3079.6875"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

and demonstration code:

```
final class ContentSizedTableView: UITableView {
    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
}
class SimpleCollCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!
}
class SimpleTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!
}
class AzdaevViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var theCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var theTableView: ContentSizedTableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        theTableView.dataSource = self
        theTableView.delegate = self
        theCollectionView.dataSource = self
        theCollectionView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SimpleTableCell", for: indexPath) as! SimpleTableCell
        c.theLabel.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
        return c
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SimpleCollCell", for: indexPath) as! SimpleCollCell
        c.theLabel.text = "\(indexPath.item)"
        return c
    }

}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Yes!Now it works. I think my weakness are constraints. Thanks a lot, you did a lot of work.